# How to convert a complex bash command to python sh

Tags: bash, shell, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the following bash command into a format that can be run by python's sh package.

```
cat "Some_File.txt" | tr [:space:] '\n' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr
```

I have very little experience with sh and some experience with python. I understand how to use sh with simple bash commands but I am having trouble figuring out how to convert this complex command into sh format due in part to the piping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using the shell.

```
from sh import sort, grep, tr, uniq

sort("-bnr", 
     uniq("-c", 
          sort(grep("-v",
                    "^\s*$",
                    tr("[:space:]",
                       "\n",
                       "Some_File.txt")))))
```